# 2 Buttons 2 EditTexts string inputs 1 TextVew output

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, concatenation

One button adds the strings in 2 EditTexts and shows the result in the TextView. Then the second button is supposed to compare these strings to 2 separate words that are hard coded. "Hello" "World". I can't even get the strings to concatenate and show output in the Textview. 
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //The stings to hold the user input
    EditText str1;
    EditText str2;
    //string to hold the output
    TextView display1;


    EditText enter1;
    EditText enter2;
    TextView WDisplay;
    Button add;
    Button display;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        str1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter1);
        str2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter2);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
        display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WDisplay);


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str1 = enter1.getText().toString();
                String str2 = enter2.getText().toString();
                display1.setText(str1);



            }
        });

        display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str1 = enter1.getText().toString();
                String str2 = enter2.getText().toString();
                display1.setText(str1);

                /*String check1;

                {
                    check1 = "Hello";
                }

                String check2;

                {
                    check2 = "World";
                }*/
            }
        });
    }'
```

I just can't seem to connect the basic to what I need for my program. Please help!

Comment: when you want to concatenate you must use some methods in line display1.setText(str1); - currently this will just show the str1

Comment: From what I am gathering from the tons of research I am doing, I found a lot of examples using the format of display1.setText(str1); I tried to use "" but that didn't work.

Comment: added answer for what you are searching. try to follow best practices when you are coding. Its not a good idea to provide you exact answer here. attached links will help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to concatenate your strings just do the following

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String enter1= str1 .getText().toString();
                String enter2= str2 .getText().toString();
                display1.setText(enter1+" "+enter2);
            }
        });
```

and for the button that compares the strings...what do you want to do after the comparision

```
    display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String str1 = enter1.getText().toString();
                    String str2 = enter2.getText().toString();
                    display1.setText(str1);
    //comparision can be done as
    if (str1.equals("Hello"){
//do anything
}

 if (str2.equals("World"){
//do anything
}

                }
            });
```

hope this helps....happy coding

Comment: Before I get to the comparing I am trying to just get the string to print out. Here is the code from just the add button:

Comment: '''String str1 = enter1.getText().toString();
                String str2 = enter2.getText().toString();
                display1.setText(str1 + "" + str2);

Comment: i have just edit the answer please use this new one

Comment: It keeps closing my virtual emulator. no string is showing in the TextView area...

Comment: add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String enter1= str1 .getText().toString();
                String enter2= str2 .getText().toString();
                display1.setText(enter1+" "+enter2);
            }
        }); this should do the work for you

Comment: your app closes before or after you click the button??

Comment: Ok I see what you did there. So you flipped what I had. The id for the EditText is get the text set into the str1/2. That worked. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203571/discussion-between-monica-breitweiser-and-unownsp).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be basic string operations. For concatenating you can use concat() method and for comparing contains() is also available in Java

Android methods like getText() and setText() you are already using, you are good to go.

Example links for your reference.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_concat.htm

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-contains-method-example/